# How can I tell if a date is before a certain time in Java?

Tags: java

For example given a java.util.Date how could I test if the time was before 12.30 PM that day?

Comment: If you have the freedom to choose, switch to using Joda Time - it's a much better API for working with date/time. new DateTime().isBefore(new DateTime().withHourOfDay(12).withMinuteOfHour(30))

Comment: @deltanovember why did you accept a wrong answer? The one you chose only tells you if the date is before 12:30 TODAY... useless. *My* answer on the other hand actually answers your question - it tells you if the date has a time that is before 12:30. Perhaps you would consider changing your accept vote to a *correct* answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [Calendar.before()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#before%28java.lang.Object%29) Method.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
Calendar givenDate = Calendar.getInstance();
givenDate.setTime(yourDate);

boolean isBefore = now.before(givenDate);
```

Comment: I think the problem he/she has is obtain the time that you calls `yourDate`

Comment: The question says, yourDate is given.

Comment: -1 Before anyone else up-votes, has anyone actually run this? It won't even compile because Calendar.getInstance() doesn't accept a date. This is a bad answer.

Comment: Use `setTime` method of `Calendar` class for setting the date.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, you're right! I don't have an editor open. I've corrected this.

Comment: @Bohemian - But the answer gives the `before` method which is the essentially important thing for which the OP looks for.

Comment: @Petar Minchev the OP asked to check if the time was before 12:30 on "...that day".  This answer checks if the time is before 12:30 today.

Comment: @msandiford - Ah, thanks for the clarification. I missed that:)

Comment: I can't believe people are upvoting this answer when IT IS WRONG! It does not answer the question!

Answer (score 2):

This works. It does the check using only the hour and minute portions of your date:

```
Date yourDate;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(yourDate);
boolean before = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 60 + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 12 * 60 + 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Date with the current date and 12:30PM as the time and do a compareTo with the other date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *GregorianCalendar* class.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the function `before()` from `java.util.Date` and set the date to compare which a combination of `Calendar.settime()` function

Answer (score 0):

Create a Date startDate and endDate with the desired dates and then you can do something similar as this:

```
if (startDate.before(endDate))
{
  System.out.println("Date is before your given date");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Bohemian has the best answer if you don't want to add dependencies, but IMO you should save yourself some time and give up on the java classes and add joda-time to your project :)

```
    static boolean isBefore1230(Date d) {
        return new DateTime(d).getMinuteOfDay() < 12 * 60 + 30;
    }
```